# Removing part of string from Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have loaded a set of data to a `Pandas DataFrame` such as below.

```
test['Consultation']
Out[13]: 
0     CONSULTATION      15.00
1     CONSULTATION      10.00
2     CONSULTATION      18.00
3     CONSULTATION       0.00
4     CONSULTATION      18.00
```

The values are contained in the **'Consultation'** column in my `DataFrame`.

Any idea how I can replace 'Consultation' with blank and convert the column data type to int64 or float?

My expected output is as below.

```
test['Consultation']
Out[13]: 
0     15.00
1     10.00
2     18.00
3      0.00
4     18.00
```

This is in order for myself to use`DataFrame.pivot_table('Consultation',rows='Provider')` to calculate the mean for my row field.

Comment: how does your original data looks?

Comment: @Amit It is just a larger subset of the above with additional columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you read the data in this way in the first place, can't you just read it into two columns? But anyway, this can be done, watch this:

```
In [35]:

df=pd.DataFrame({'Consultation':['CONSULTATION      15.00',
'CONSULTATION      10.00',
'CONSULTATION      18.00',
'CONSULTATION       0.00',
'CONSULTATION      18.00']})
In [36]:

import re
In [37]:

p=re.compile('[0-9.]+')
In [38]:

df['Cons']=df['Consultation'].apply(lambda x: float(p.findall(x)[0]))
In [39]:

print df
              Consultation  Cons
0  CONSULTATION      15.00    15
1  CONSULTATION      10.00    10
2  CONSULTATION      18.00    18
3  CONSULTATION       0.00     0
4  CONSULTATION      18.00    18

[5 rows x 2 columns]
In [40]:

df.dtypes
Out[40]:
Consultation     object
Cons            float64
dtype: object
```

In your case, you can overwrite the original `df['Consultation']` by `df['Consultation']=df['Consultation'].apply(lambda x: float(p.findall(x)[0]))`

Comment: The data is a bit distorted that is why when I initially read with pd.read_csv, the column is mixed with string and int. It is my wish to remove the string part to apply aggregation functions on that columns.

Comment: Ok, understood. I guess the solution above based on `regular expression` should be able to do the trick. Unless the prefix string also contains number-like stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That totally did it for me. The last comment in your answer solved my problem, I just need to understand on it works now.

Comment: `re.compile('[0-9.]+')` grabs the sub-string containing only numbers and dots. That is a list, so we take the first item of it using `[0]`. Then we convert it using `float()`. That's all. (And it's why the prefix must not contain number-like strings)